# QGIS get current Layername in Rule

Tags: qgis

in QGIS I´d like to label geometries with it´s layer name.

```
Example: Name of Polygon Layer "testlayer" -> each Polygon is labeled with "testlayer"
```

Is there some way to access the current layer name in rules like:

```
layer_property(_self, 'name')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you open the *vector layer properties*, there's a tab *Variables*. Some of them are pre-defined and one of the pre-defined ones is `layer_name`. To use it, prefix it with an `@`.

```
@layer_name
```

You can also use the id or add your own variables in there.

For more information regarding variables you can read these [excellent](http://nyalldawson.net/2015/12/exploring-variables-in-qgis-2-12-part-1/) [blog](http://nyalldawson.net/2015/12/exploring-variables-in-qgis-pt-2-project-management/) [posts](http://nyalldawson.net/2015/12/exploring-variables-in-qgis-pt-3-layer-level-variables/).

Comment: I did look for it but it sadly does not appear as a choice (second column) in the expression dialog

Comment: I cannot see it either in the list, but this is doing it! Thanks!

Comment: I fixed this some time ago, not sure if already in 2.18 but certainly in 3.0 this will appear in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
layer_property('Layername','name')
```

Which works. I have not seen a $currentlayer function yet.

Comment: Just to expand on this answer.  Check out the explanation panel on the right of the expression builder.  It'll show you how to use the function as well as what other properties you can apply.

Comment: Yes I know this and the help panel (but thanks for the hint ;) As far as I understand your anser I would have to set Layername for each Layer 'by Hand' which is to much work that´s why I was asking for a variable like `_self`or `$this`. With this I could just copy the expression to each layer property.

Comment: In this case you should use a python script. Reformulate your question and ask for it, somebody will probably help you. And try a little by yourself. I'm yet to learn pygis, but it seems definitely worth the time.